# Dialog appears slowly because of a specific method, how could I use Threads here?

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

I would like to understand how should I use Threads in this case? I have a dialog appears with a textview in it. The textview recives its information from a method which needs about 1 second to be completed. But I want the dialog appears immediately and I want the data to be loaded in a thread, then I want to make that specific data appear 1 second later in the dialog (which has been on the screen for 1 second now).

So I have a method `GetData()` which returns the data (String). I have the dialog which appears after clicking a button:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    TextView tv= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText(GetData());    
    dialog.show;
    }
}
```

How could I do it? Thanks in advance!

Okay, Asynctask, but how can I touch the textview inside?

```
//AsyncTask

    public class DefaultAsyncTask extends
    AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

        int myProgress;

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            return null;
        }


 }
```

Comment: use a asynctask in onpostExecute() display dialog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap up the time-consuming code in an `AsyncTask` attach it to `Dialog`'s events:

The task:

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        //-- put get data code here --
        //-- if this takes too much time, repeatedly check "isCancelled()", and exit if its true--
        return "the string result";
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public void ShowDialog(Context c){
    Dialog d = new Dialog(c);
    final TextView t = new TextView(c);
    d.setContentView(t);

    //--setup the task to update text--
    final MyTask w = new MyTask(){
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            t.setText(s);
        }
    };

    //--setup the dialog to run task when shown--
    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            w.execute();
        }
    });

    //--setup the dialog to kill task if its dismissed--
    d.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            w.cancel(true);
        }
    });


    //-- show the dialog--
    d.show();
}
```

Above code is just an example, elegant way is to extend `Dialog` class and place this code there to make it a `TaskRunnerDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

Using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Hope this helps, Yaron

Comment: Okay but this is in a dialog. I am a beginner AyncTask user, could you somehow help? I updated my code with a defeault asynctask class. Since my textview is defined inside the dialog, I cannot touch it in the asynctask.

Answer (score -1):

Normal Thread will not run any ui Components ,it will produce error use this uithread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new   ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
TextView tv= (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
tv.setText(GetData());    
dialog.show;

                }
            });
```